# testcafe - Upload file

Tags: vue.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to test an upload screen, but I'm having a problem with the .setFilesToUpload. No file is being uploaded.

edit: If I debug, unlock page, click on upload file and select ANY other file, the field is filled with the script's file

I tried

.setFilesToUpload(Selector('input').withAttribute('type','file'), '../src/assets/logo.png')

and

.setFilesToUpload(Selector("#customInputFile"), "../src/assets/icon.png")

But in both cases, no file is being uploaded. The screen waits for it, but nothing happens.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="file-container" v-if="!image">
      <label>{{ label }}</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          @dragover="handleDragAndDrop"
          @dragenter="handleDragAndDrop"
          @dragleave="handleDragAndDrop($event, true)"
          @drop="onFileChange"
          v-bind:class="{ error: dataError }"
          :placeholder="dataPlaceholder"
          :value="dataFileName"
          readonly

        />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="file-button" type="button" @click="launchFilePicker">
            SELECT A FILE
          </button>
        </span>
      </div>
      <input
        type="file"
        :value="filePayload"
        @input="onFileChange"
        ref="file"
        id="customInputFile"
        style="display: none"

      />
      <span v-if="dataError" class="errorMessage">{{ dataErrorMessage }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="file-container" v-else>
      <img :src="image" />
      <button @click="removeImage">Remove image</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I need to upload a file and pass the test.

Comment: It is unclear from your post what problems you are experiencing with the `setFilesToUpload` action. Would you please describe them in greater detail?

Comment: No file is being uploaded.

Comment: TestCafe emulates an upload instead of the native upload. Could you please check out the `value` or `files` properties of your file input after the upload action?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: If I debug, unlock page, click on upload file and select ANY other file, the field is filled with the script's file (logo.png)

Comment: import { Selector } from "testcafe";

fixture`CreateApp`.page`http://localhost:8080/`;

test("CreateApp", async t => {
  await t
    .typeText(Selector("#customInput"), "My new App")
    .setFilesToUpload(
      Selector("input").withAttribute("type", "file"),
      "logo.png"
    )
    .setFilesToUpload(Selector("#customInputFile"), "logo.png")
    .wait(5000)
    .click(Selector('#customInputFile'))
    .debug()

Comment: For example:
`
    fixture \`upload example\`
        .page \`https://davidwalsh.name/demo/multiple-file-upload.php\`; 

    test('t', async t => {
        await t
            .setFilesToUpload('#filesToUpload', './upload-example.js')
            .debug();
    });
`
==========================================================
Video: https://www.screencast.com/t/woVmqHqXk9j

Comment: Nice. I did it. I have an hidden field, that actually is the file input. I make it not hidden and did like you. By console, I can see that this input got the file. But it's not showing on screen: https://ibb.co/kQR60cj

Comment: It is normal behavior. As I said before, TestCafe emulates an upload instead of the native upload. Because of this a native field cannot show selected files. TestCafe mocks the `files` and `value` properties and also emits the `change` event. All files will be sent to the server if you submit your form.

Comment: Nice! I haven't the onchange . I put it now it works! :D THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just need to add the onChange on my input, to call my script, that was only on input.

Thank you very much